# How to replace path in text file with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a problem with replace text in Powershell. For e.g.

When I use:

`(Get-Content C:\TEMP\App.config) -replace "one","two" | Set-Content C:\TEMP\App.config`

it works. But when I use:

`(Get-Content C:\TEMP\App.config) -replace "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 10\Reader\AcroRd32.exe","C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe" | Set-Content C:\TEMP\App.config`

is doesn't work. I search a lot of info in Google or documentation but still have a problem.

Can anybody help? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [-replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator) operator uses regex on the **search** string and replaces that with another string.
That **replacement** string is a normal, unescaped string.

Since your path has characters in it that have special meaning in regex, like the backslash, you need to escape the search string by prepending a backslash in front of every such special character.

Regex has its own static method for that: `[regex]::Escape()`

Also worth mentioning is that if you read the file including the `-Raw` switch, so it wil become a single multline string, replacing values is much faster.

```
$search  = [Regex]::Escape('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 10\Reader\AcroRd32.exe')
$replace = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe'

(Get-Content -Path 'C:\TEMP\App.config' -Raw) -replace $search, $replace | Set-Content -Path 'C:\TEMP\App.config'
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be aware that the `-replace` command uses ***regex***. It should work, if you *escape* the replace string:

```
$searchString = [Regex]::Escape('C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader 10\Reader\AcroRd32.exe')
$replaceString = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe'

(Get-Content C:\TEMP\App.config) -replace $searchString, $replaceString | Set-Content C:\TEMP\App.config
```

Comment: `$replaceString` should **not** be escaped